# what is hyper-tournament?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, hypergraphs

I know the definition of the tournament ( a directed graph obtained after assigning direction to edges of the complete graph). I tried on search on internet did not get anything.

**Question:** What is hyper-graphs means?

**Motivation :** This term is mentioned in this [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000009000774)

Comment: If the term is *defined* in that paper, what does the definition in that paper say?  What is unsatisfactory about *that* definition?

Comment: In the paper it is not defined

Comment: Then why does your post literally say "*This term* **is** *defined in this paper?*"

Comment: I mean to say mentioned in the paper

Comment: Anyways, my expectation is that a Tournament is a complete directed graph which corresponds to a set of two-player games played between $n$ teams with one game per pair of teams and a designated player.  A hyper-tournament on the other hand is a complete directed hypergraph on $n$ vertices of a specific edge size $k$ which corresponds to a series of $k$-player games played by between each subset of $k$ players from $n$ teams total with a designated winner for each.

Comment: Whereas in a graph, an edge has two vertices, a hypergraph is not limited to just having two vertices per edge and can have any number of vertices per edge.

Comment: Hypertournaments are also mentioned in the titles of two of the papers cited as references in the paper you linked to. Perhaps the term is defined in one of those papers? Anyway, have you tried asking the authors of the paper for the definition?

Comment: @JMoravitz I know nothing about directed hypergraphs. If I was going to guess what a "hypertournament" is just from the name, I might guess that it assigns a winner to every hyperedge, or I might guess that it assigns a linear ordering to every hyperedge, or that it assigns a winner and a loser to every hyperedge, or that it partitions every hyperedge into two nonempty sets, winners and losers. Are you giving us the standard definition, or are you just guessing?

Comment: @bof It was a guess.  After searching a moment, **the second result on google** for the search phrase `hypertournament` (*sssss, did you google search the term?  it was rather quick to find*) was [this](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0024379502007267/1-s2.0-S0024379502007267-main.pdf?_tid=43ca63fe-c441-11e7-a698-00000aacb35e&acdnat=1510117205_a2b761f38c4aa492a75f52dc3a7c5b82) and it defines it as I did with the correction that it assigns a linear ordering to each hyperedge (*as bof pointed out was likely the case*).  As for definition of hypergraph, that is included in any standard textbook and wiki.

Comment: It's rather unfortunate that Googling "hypertournament graph theory" now yields this as the second result.

Comment: @JMoravitz To be fair, the terminology of graph theory is chaotic enough that, in my opinion, there's a nonzero probability that the term "hypertournament" has a different meaning in the paper the OP is reading than the one you found by googling, and a pretty good chance that someone somewhere has used the term with a different meaning.

Answer (score 3):

Before the definition of a hypertournament, here are some preliminaries. A hypergraph is a generalization of a graph in the following sense:

- A graph is defined by a set $V$ of vertices and a set $E$ of edges which are unordered pairs $\{v,w\}$ with $v, w \in V$.
- A hypergraph is defined by a set $V$ of vertices and a set $E$ of "hyperedges" (often just edges) which are subsets of $V$ of arbitrary size.
- Often (as in this paper) we talk about $k$-uniform hypergraphs: in this case, all hyperedges must have size $k$. That is, each edge is a set $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k\}$ where $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k$ are distinct elements of $V$.

In particular, an ordinary graph is a $2$-uniform hypergraph.

Just as a complete graph is a graph which includes all $\binom{|V|}{2}$ possible edges, a complete $k$-uniform hypergraph is defined to be the hypergraph whose edges are all $\binom{|V|}{k}$ possible subsets of $V$ of size $k$.

Finally, a $k$-hypertournament (as defined in [the paper referenced in the question](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000009000774)) is the corresponding generalization of a tournament: it is obtained from a complete $k$-uniform hypergraph by assigning directions to each hyperedge.

What does it mean to assign a direction to a hyperedge? It means that we replace the set $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k\}$ by an ordered $k$-tuple of these vertices, in some order: $(v_{\pi(1)}, v_{\pi(2)}, \dots, v_{\pi(k)}\}$ for some permutation $\pi$ of $\{1,2,\dots,k\}$.

For example:

- All ordinary tournaments are $2$-hypertournaments: a directed edge from $v$ to $w$ is just an ordered pair $(v,w)$.
- One possible $3$-hypertournament on the vertices $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is the one whose oriented hyperedges are the triples $\{(3,2,1), (2,1,4), (3,1,4), (3,4,2)\}$. This is one out of $(3!)^4$ different possibilities.
- If you held a [Hearts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearts) competition between $n$ players in which each of the $\binom n4$ sets of players play a game together, you could record the $4$-tuples $(1^{\text{st}}\text{ place}, 2^{\text{nd}}\text{ place}, 3^{\text{rd}}\text{ place}, 4^{\text{th}}\text{ place})$ for each game played, and that would be a $4$-hypertournament. (Assuming there are no ties.)

Comment: Is this the only definition of "hypertournament" in the literature, or the most common one?

Comment: This is the one the question is asking about. Out of the top 10 Google Scholar results for "hypertournament", 8 used this definition, and the other 2 were talking about the unrelated concept of a "hypertournament matrix". Also, I think this definition is the most natural one, so I think we can consider it pretty well accepted.